# Problemas con sklearn fit_transfom

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Tengo una base de datos que en la primera columna tiene strings y en las siguientes coumnas tiene floats.

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='mean')
values = imputer.fit_transform(movies_v2)
```

pero me reporta el siguiente error:
ValueError: Cannot use mean strategy with non-numeric data:
could not convert string to float: 'Avatar\xa0'

Comment: De antemano muchas gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

No puedes usar como estrategia la media para imputar valores en variables categóricas. Simplemente no incluyas esa columna.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer 


movies_v2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {"title":("Avatar", "Reservoir Dogs", "Blade Runner",
              "El club de la lucha", np.nan, "Blade Runner"),
     "foo": (5.8, 7.9, 8.3, np.nan, 7.5, np.nan),
     "bar": (np.nan, 8.2, 8.6, 6.2, 2.8, 5.2)}
    )

imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='mean')
values = imputer.fit_transform(movies_v2.iloc[:, 1:])
```

> ```
> >>> values)
>
> [[5.8   6.2  ]
>  [7.9   8.2  ]
>  [8.3   8.6  ]
>  [7.375 6.2  ]
>  [7.5   2.8  ]
>  [7.375 5.2  ]]
> ```

No se si tu primera columna tienen valores nulos a los que quieras inmutar un valor.En tal caso, ten en cuenta que `SimpleImputer` soporta datos categóricos en forma de cadena son representados por
`pandas.Categorical` pero lógicamente solo cuando se usan las estrategias
'most_frequent' o 'constant', no para `'mean'`.

```
imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='most_frequent')
values = imputer.fit_transform(movies_v2.iloc[:, 0:1])
```

> ```
> >>> values
>
> [['Avatar']
>  ['Reservoir Dogs']
>  ['Blade Runner']
>  ['El club de la lucha']
>  ['Blade Runner']
>  ['Blade Runner']]
> ```